# Haskell custom data type expression

Tags: haskell

If I have the custom data type as follows:

```
data MyType :: * -> *  where
Zero:: MyType a
One:: a -> MyType a
Two:: MyType a -> MyType b -> MyType (a,b)
```

Is it the same as writing them as:

```
 data MyType a = Zero
             | One a
```

Is the above correct? And how do I represent Two?

Comment: Both definitions of `Zero` and `One` are equivalent. However, the constructor `Two` can not be represented outside a GADT.

Comment: @chi I tried to do it in the first way, but it returned an error saying Illegal kind signature MyType?

Comment: @xcoder Do you have `KindSignatures` enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done via GADT. The trick is to enable KindSignature in your program.